# CMake and Window .Lib Files

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I have been struggling to find an answer to this question across Stackoverflow, at least one that I understand. I recently bought CLion and want to port an older project from Visual Studio over to it. But I have no idea how to link or add .lib files to my project. I need to link Xinput and DSound.

In Visual Studio I just added the headers and then added these to the top of my file

**#pragma comment(lib, "XInput.lib")**

**#pragma comment(lib, "Dsound.lib")**

I just have absolutely no idea how to link to those libs using CMake as I am a complete beginner with it.

Any Help would be gladly appreciated

This is my current CMake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project("Handmade_Hero")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

add_executable("Handmade_Hero" ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

**UPDATE**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Handmade_Hero)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

add_executable(Handmade_Hero ${SOURCE_FILES})

set( LIBS XInput DSound )
target_link_libraries(Handmade_Hero ${LIBS} )
```

My Compiler now throws the following errors:

```
PATH\ClionProjects\Handmade-Hero\main.cpp:3:20: fatal error: Xinput.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Xinput.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Handmade_Hero.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Handmade_Hero.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Handmade_Hero.dir/main.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Handmade_Hero.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Handmade_Hero.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Handmade_Hero] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Handmade_Hero.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Handmade_Hero.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'Handmade_Hero' failed
```

Comment: So, you should use `include_directories` for tell CMake, which directory contains given header. Where have you `Xinput.h` file?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: They all seem to be located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include

Comment: Hmm, given directory seems to be related to Visual Studio. Its headers may be incompatible with Mingw and CLion. But you can try to use them: `include_directories("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include")`.

Comment: The actual .lib files seem to be located here 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86'. When I add include_directories("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include") the actual editor complains " '('. ')' or argument expected, got "" "

Comment: You should use UNIX slash '/' instead. And maybe use `LINK_DIRECTORIES` to set the lib path separately. `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` for headers.

Comment: Thank you so much, that seems to have done the trick!

Comment: @Richard I am stuck with the same problem. Can you share your cmakelists.txt, so that I can get it running too?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add these after your CMakeLists.txt

```
SET( LIBS XInput DSound )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(projectname ${LIBS} )
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for responding, I added those two lines and now throwing the following error "Error:Cannot specify link libraries for target "Actual Project Name" which is not built by this project."

Comment: @Richard: Such error means that first argument for `target_link_libraries` differs from one for `add_executable`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the names from add_executable and target_link_libraries are the same. I updated my post

Comment: @Richard: Is "Project Name" a *real* name for your project? Normally, CMake targets don't contain spaces.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: It isn't, my real project name has an underscore. I am actually following a tutorial HandMade Hero, so the project name is Handmade_Hero

Comment: Please, use actual names in your code in the question. If you do not want reveal original name, choose other one: `MyProject`, `my_project`...  And provide error message with actual name.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I am sorry for making that mistake, I updated my post to include the actual project name as well as the errors the compiler is throwing.