# How to add .lib libraries in cmake on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake

My problem is the exact one as [CMake and Window .Lib Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380787/cmake-and-window-lib-files) but I couldn't make it work with the solution proposed there. Here's my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(roosek2 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)

add_executable(roosek2
  main.cpp
  qml.qrc
  DecodeH264AndStream.cpp
)

add_library(ctmedia_codec SHARED IMPORTED)
add_library(ctmedia_drm SHARED IMPORTED)
add_library(ctstream SHARED IMPORTED)
#link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win_bin/lib/x64)
set_target_properties(ctmedia_codec PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win_bin/lib/x64/CTMedia.lib)
set_target_properties(ctstream PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win_bin/lib/x64/CTStream.lib)

include_directories("include")
target_compile_definitions(roosek2
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(roosek2
  PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick ctmedia_codec ctstream)
```

but I get that `ctmedia_codec` was `NOT_FOUND`

I also tried `link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win_bin/lib/x64)` and doing simply

```
target_link_libraries(roosek2
      PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick CTMedia CTStream)
```

but then I get that it couldn't find `-lCTMedia -lCTStream`

So how can I add .lib files to my cmake project on Windows?

Comment: "but I get that `ctmedia_codec` was `NOT_FOUND`" - Please, add the **exact error message** into the question post.

Comment: What CMake commands do you run when configuring CMake? What is your CMake generator? Does the `CTMedia.lib` actually exist in the path `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win_bin/lib/x64`? Please provide the **full** error message that you are seeing.